# Создание запроса на вычитание последних двух строк

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос, события

Есть БД MySQL запись в неё происходит раз в час с C# (но эт не важно )
Есть таблица (на рис) надо сделать запрос в БД а точнее Event что бы каждый час TecCMC отнимался от TecCMC предпоследнего и записывался в соседнюю SutCMC, то есть:
Две даты последних записанных: TecCMC SutCMC
2016-01-26 09:00:00 10 0
2016-01-26 10:00:00 15 5
Должно примерно так выглядеть, но не получается построить запрос
Как я понимаю вид должен быть :

```
SELECT 
  `diet`.`TecCMC`,
  `diet1`.`TecCMC`,
  `diet`.`DataTime`,
  `diet1`.`DataTime`
FROM
  `diet` `diet1`
  INNER JOIN `diet` ON (`diet1`.`TecCMC` - `diet`.`TecCMC`)
  AND (`diet1`.`DataTime` < `diet`.`DataTime`)
```

[image: Заполняется так :)]

После постройки запроса должно так выглядеть :)
[image: Вот так выглядеть должно]

Подскажите как это реализовать, можно реализацию ещё в c# представить, БД взаимодействует с#

Сейчас всё объясню, раз в час мне в ТecCMC приходит значение Тес - Текущее (оно считывается с сервера ОPC), его надо вычесть с предпоследним значением (т.к. она раз в час будет увеличиваться (обычный счётчик)), почему поменялись значения на картинках всё просто (я ручками подправил БД для наглядности) Получается 3 Поля Текущее Суточные и Месячные. Суточный вычисляется по разнице Текущего

Создаётся программа на C# Для сбора и хранения энергоресурсов завода.
Приходят значения с контроллера, обрабатываются и записываются в БД.

Каждый раз происходит новая запись, запись происходит раз в час по таймеру в c#
Сумматор стоит в самом контроллере он сам считает поступившие в него импульсы и конечный результат я получаю раз в час через c#

На картинке видно таблицы: DataTime, TecCMC, SutCMC, MesCMC - Время,

Текущее(значение которое сразу после контроллера записывается в БД),

Суточные должна раз в сутки обнулять своё значение и считать заново,

Месячные обнуление происходит раз в месяц.

Comment: Для задачи оперирования с соседними строками БД обычно делают автоинкрементное поле id, и обязательно индексируют его, тогда не будет проблемы получить разницу между записями сделав select a.value - b.value from tab a inner join tab b on b.id = a.id-1

Comment: Ничего не понятно в вопросе. почему раз в час, почему именно 2 записи. Как из значений 7 и 5 на первом экране получилось 20. И что происходит с временем в записях, до этого минуты были а потом пропали, зато какие то 8 утра появились, которых не было

Comment: Если нужно править данные по мере поступления, то лучше ставить триггер на insert, тогда и последнюю строчку проще найти, и столбец подменить. Иначе запросы будут "тяжёлые".

Comment: А как вы записи в таблице отличаете, какие у вас месячные, какие суточные и текущие ? И что значит "раз в час приходит значение" ? в каком виде оно приходит, правится какая то существующая запись, или добавляется новая запись. И что если с БД что то случится тогда, когда вы хотели, что бы сработал event и в итоге он будет пропущен и успеют "придти"  2 значения ? Может стоит брать как то все _оперативные_ данные за последние сутки и суммировать. И что после "вычитания значения" должно произойти с записью которую вычитали

Comment: ах, да если с БД что-то случится есть бекап, у меня есть текс боксы в него должны выводиться Суточные значение с изменением раз в час Если честно, я сам уже запутался как правильно это реализовать.